# React-table[v7] rendering with Storybook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, storybook

I am attempting to render the react-table component in Storybook https://storybook.js.org/

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at decorateColumnTree (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:210768)
at vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:211338
at mountMemo (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:186644)
at Object.useMemo (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:186866)
at Object.useMemo (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:217699)
at useTable (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:211337)
at Table (main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:17507)
at renderWithHooks (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:186083)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:188317)
at beginWork$1 (vendors~main.4c20d65610ba8d62ac56.bundle.js:189461)
```

Following through the culprit of the error, it seems that decorateColumnTree is receiving undefined for the columns argument. https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/1d8ffb18f7afc862db5d4f1da5cfc6781ed10553/src/hooks/useTable.js#L166-L169

```
storybook version: ^5.1.9

react-table version: ^7.0.0-rf.15
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some time, I have figured it out. It was mainly a problem with data and variable scoping.

Initially, I was doing this

```
import dummyData from './mockData'

table.addDecorator(withKnobs).add('Table', () =>
  React.createElement(() => {
    return (
      <Table
        columns={dummyData.columns}
        data={dummyData.data}
      />
    )
  })
)
```

however, `dummyData` was undefined within `React.createElement` so i opted to then do:

```
table.addDecorator(withKnobs).add('NextTable', () =>
  React.createElement(() => {
    return (
      <MockTableComponent />
    )
  })
)
```

where the mock data and mock columns are memoized within the `MockTableComponent` which is rendering `<Table />`